# How to Navigate one of the two screens to users correctly in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

Recently I am developing first ever app in Flutter and I know the basics only.
So here's the problem which I am facing currently.

I have to Navigate One of the two screens, either Register or Home page according to old/new user, So what I did is here.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'Register.dart';
import 'HomePage.dart';

class Authenticate extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AuthenticateState createState() => _AuthenticateState();
}

class _AuthenticateState extends State<Authenticate> {
  String _userName = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getUserName();
  }

  _getUserName() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _userName = pref.getString('userName') ?? "";
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_userName == "") {
      print('name : $_userName  , NEW user'); // ERROR - why it's printing on console for old User ?
      return Register();
    } else {
      return HomePage(_userName);
    }
  }
}
```

So the problem is, even if I am opening app through old user, it is printing the debug code written for new user and there's around 0.3 sec screen visibility of Register screen.

So what should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The print is happening because this line of code:

`SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();`

is asynchronous, which means that it might invoke in some later point in time. Because of that the `build` method is called first, then your `_getUserName` method finished, which causes a `setState` and invokes a `build` method again.

You might want to show some kind of loader screen until sharedPrefernces is initialized and then decide wheter to show `Register` or `Home` page.

Example code:

```
class _AuthenticateState extends State<Authenticate> {
  String _userName = "";
  bool _isLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getUserName();
  }

  _getUserName() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _userName = pref.getString('userName') ?? "";
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_isLoading) {
      return Center(child: CupertinoActivityIndicator());
    } else if (_userName == "") {
      print('name : $_userName  , NEW user'); // ERROR - why it's printing on console for old User ?
      return Register();
    } else {
      return HomePage(_userName);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class _AuthenticateState extends State<Authenticate> {
  String _userName;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getUserName();
  }

  _getUserName() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _userName = pref.getString('userName') ?? '';
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_userName == null) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    } else if (_userName == '') {
      print('name : $_userName  , NEW user');
      return Register();
    } else {
      return HomePage(_userName);
    }
  }
}
```

In this case, `_userName` is `null` initially and will only be assigned a value after the `_getUserName()` returns either an empty String or an old userName. When null, the widget will build a progress indicator instead. If you don't want that, just return a `Container()`.

Comment: Thank you so much , 

Actually I am using await and sync first time , So wasn't having any idea.
Now I am feeling dumb.
Gonna explore it fully :)

Comment: https://youtu.be/SmTCmDMi4BY - this is a really cool video on the matter